# setTimeout not working with function inside it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with `setTimeout()` function. This is my code so far:

```
$('#start').click(function(event) {
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 4000 + 1)) + 4000; // creates a random value between 4000 and 10000 and store it in a variable 
    setTimeout("$('.reflex').css('background','red')",result); // this works great
    setTimeout(startTimer(),result); //this code triggers without delay
});
```

Got it? When using a function inside setTimeout the delay doesn't apply and the function executes instantly.

What can I do?

Comment: `setTimeout(startTimer, result);`You want to pass function reference

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` takes a function, not the results of the function as its first parameter.

```
setTimeout(startTimer,result);
```

Note, no `()` after `startTimer`.

Comment: Thanks gonna wait 15 minutes and mark this as correct answer